React ag-grid server global filter infinite loop when search
I am trying  to create a global filter for React ag-grid aka react grid
the issue I have is infinite loop ( I could see the search results but when searching the component keeps request the server and keep refresh with loading spinners under the search results .
I have revised quick filter example but still unable to solve the issue.
Here is my component
export const AgSpaces = () => {
  const { workspaceId } = useParams();
  const gridRef = useRef<AgGridReact>(null);
  const { theme } = useThemeStore();
  const [searchParam, setSearchParam] = useState("");

  const [colDefs] = useState<ColDef[]>([
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID" },
    { field: "name", headerName: "Name" },
    { field: "groupCount", headerName: "Group Count", sortable: true },
    { field: "listCount", headerName: "List Count", sortable: true },
    {
      field: "description",
      headerName: "Description",
      valueGetter: (params) => params.data.description || "-",
    },
    {
      field: "color",
      headerName: "Color",
      cellRenderer: (params: { value: string }) => {
        const color = params.value;
        if (!color) return null;

        return (
          <div
            className="w-5 h-5 border border-gray-300 rounded"
            style={{ backgroundColor: params.value }}
          ></div>
        );
      },
    },
    {
      field: "createdAt",
      headerName: "Created At",
      valueFormatter: (params) => {
        const date = params.value;
        return date ? dateFormat(date) : "";
      },
    },
    {
      field: "updatedAt",
      headerName: "Updated At",
      valueFormatter: (params) => {
        const date = params.value;
        return date ? dateFormat(date) : "";
      },
    },
  ]);

  const datasource = (workspaceId: string) => {
    return {
      getRows: async (params: IServerSideGetRowsParams) => {
        const { startRow, endRow, sortModel } = params.request;

        // Process the sortModel for a single column sorting
        let sort = sortModel?.[0]; // Assuming there's only one sort model
        let sortParam = sort ? `${sort.colId}:${sort.sort}` : undefined; // Convert to "column:order" format

        // Fetch data based on startRow, endRow, sort, and search
        const response = await fetchSpacesByWorkspaceId(
          workspaceId ?? "",
          "groupCount,listCount",
          startRow ? startRow + 1 : 1,
          endRow,
          sortParam, // Pass the single sort string
          searchParam
        );

        if (response) {
          params.success({
            rowData: response.spaces,
            rowCount: response.total, // Set total row count for pagination
          });
        } else {
          params.fail();
        }
      },
    };
  };

  const onGridReady = useCallback((event: GridReadyEvent) => {
    event.api.resetColumnState();
  }, []);


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="">
        <span>Quick Filter:</span>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="filter-text-box"
          placeholder="Filter..."
          onChange={(e)=> setSearchParam(e.target.value)}
          className="rounded m-3 p-1 border bg-background"
        />
      </div>
      <div
        className={`${
          theme === "dark" ? "ag-theme-quartz-dark" : "ag-theme-quartz"
        }`}
        style={{ height: 500 }}
      >
        <AgGridReact
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
          columnDefs={colDefs}
          rowModelType={"serverSide"}
          pagination={true} // Enable pagination
          paginationPageSize={20} // Rows per page
          cacheBlockSize={20} // Rows fetched in each request (sync with paginationPageSize)
          animateRows={true}
          serverSideDatasource={datasource(workspaceId as string)}
          //onPaginationChanged={onPaginationChanged} // Listen for page size changes
          paginationPageSizeSelector={[20, 50, 100, 1000, 10000]}
          defaultColDef={{ filter: true }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

I would appreciate any answers and/or comments

In my situation, the total number of backend servers does not change when getting search results.
That makes the grid load waiting for more rows to load. while in the case of search, the total should decrease
